# Scanner object return type

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a memory game in Java as my first college-level Java assignment and I am stumped with the way Java handles user input.

The memory game requires the user to choose between 3 different difficulty modes: easy, medium, and hard. I thought this would be relatively straightforward as I could just use `Scanner` and `nextLine` to get the user's desired difficulty.

It is not as easy as I assumed and I'm completely stuck on how to fix the error, I am using the easy mode to test out my current progress, but when I input 'easy' the code in the 'easy' conditional never runs.

A conditional at the very bottom runs instead, that being an else statement for the hard mode that runs if neither easy nor medium is chosen.

I have tried printing out my input to make sure it says 'easy' with correct case and spelling, and still the 'easy' conditional does not run.

My guess is that `nextLine()` is not returning correctly, or it is returning correctly and `==` just is not the right way to check for equality. I am very new to Java and I could very easily be wrong, so any and all advice is much appreciated. Thank you all!

```
    Scanner select_diff = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please select a difficulty. Choose between easy, medium, or hard: ");
    ArrayList<String> difficulty_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    difficulty_list.add("easy");
    difficulty_list.add("medium");
    difficulty_list.add("hard");
    String difficulty = select_diff.nextLine(); //takes user input
    System.out.println(difficulty); //to double check that I input 'easy'
    //difficulty = difficulty.strip(); I thought these 2 lines were the issue, they were not
    //difficulty = difficulty.toLowerCase();
    while (difficulty_list.contains(difficulty) == false) //this while loop handles invalid input
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again.");
        difficulty = select_diff.nextLine();
    }
    if (difficulty == "easy") //this conditional is never entered
```

Comment: I would simplify the `while` condition to: `while (!difficulty_list.contains(difficulty))` Also, you look like you come from a Python background. Java conventions dictate that variables should be lowerCamelCase i.e. `dificultyList`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you should use `String#equals` for equality check when dealing with strings. You could also normalize the user's input by calling `toLowerCase()`. When requesting input, you should also prompt the user e.g. *"Choose a difficulty"*.

Also, you can define constant (`final`) values or even an `enum` to represent difficulty choices.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Game {
    public static final String MODE_EASY   = "easy";
    public static final String MODE_MEDIUM = "medium";
    public static final String MODE_HARD   = "hard";

    private static final List<String> DIFFICULTY_OPTIONS =
        List.of(MODE_EASY, MODE_MEDIUM, MODE_HARD);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Choose a difficulty: ");
        String selectedDifficulty = userInput.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        while (!DIFFICULTY_OPTIONS.contains(selectedDifficulty)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again.");
            System.out.print("Choose a difficulty: ");
            selectedDifficulty = userInput.nextLine();
        }
        if (selectedDifficulty.equals(MODE_EASY)) {
            System.out.println("You selected easy mode!");
        }
        // Do more stuff...
        userInput.close(); // Close when done gathering input
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all! Yes, as you might have guessed, I am from a Python background, which would explain the confusion. Thank you for making my transition into java smoother.